# v-model in Toast UI editor for Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use the [Vue.js wrapper](https://github.com/nhn/tui.editor/tree/master/apps/vue-editor) for [Toast UI](https://github.com/nhn/tui.editor) and I can't get the v-model to work.

I followed [this tutorial](https://vuejsexamples.com/toast-ui-editor-for-vue/) to make the following code:

```js
import { Editor } from '@toast-ui/vue-editor'

export default {
  components: {
    editor: Editor
  },
  data () {
    return {
      editorText: 'Bloop'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clicker () {
      alert(this.editorText)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <editor v-model="editorText"/>
    <button @click="clicker">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

The Toast UI editor is empty on page load. Anything typed into the editor is not saved in the "editorText" variable because the alert shows the initial value. I feel like I must be making a very simple mistake.

I would like to set the text in the editor when the page opens, and then get the markdown text from the editor when the button is pressed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That tutorial uses an old library ([see repo](https://github.com/nhn/toast-ui.vue-editor)). You are using this another ([see repo](http://@toast-ui/vue-editor)), It doesn´t have allowed `v-model`, instead use `initialValue`:

```html
<editor :initialValue="editorText" ref="toastuiEditor"/>
```

And get html by this way:

```js
// ...
methods: {
    getHtml() {
        let html = this.$refs.toastuiEditor.invoke('getHtml');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful for using initial value when the page loads. Is there a way to set the value after the page has been loaded?

Comment: Okay, after hunting around, I found that this will work: this.$refs.toastuiEditor.invoke('setHtml', this.editorText)

Comment: If your initial text is markdown you can use "setMarkdown" method: this.$refs.toastuiEditor.invoke('setMarkdown', this.editorText)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.$refs.toastuiEditor.invoke('setHTML', this.editorText)
```

This worked for me! They have changed `setHtml` to `setHTML`